# How to place images in radio group in android along with radio button in android

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

I want to design radio buttons along with corresponding text and images.when I tried with linear layout inside the radio group,all the radio buttons are enabled.how can fix this

Comment: Can you share your xml or code where you do that?

Comment: Where is xml? Where is your output?

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can use image as well as radiobutton inside the radiogroup

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: when I tried with this,I can select all the radio buttons at a time

Comment: how do you add these image they are inside drawble or mipmap asset ? @DevikaReji

Comment: It is worked but i want to design vertically like,first a radio button,an image then a text

Comment: if it worked please accept and upvote the answer for future explorer @DevikaReji

Comment: use linear layout set its orientation to horizontal you can set radiogroup and textview side by side @DevikaReji

Answer (score 0):

> I have designed the same layout as below. It might help you.

```
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioSubject"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/subject_selector"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/txt_subject"
                    android:textColor="@color/radio_text_selector"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioChapter"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/chapter_selector"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/txt_chapter"
                    android:textColor="@color/radio_text_selector"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioTopic"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/topic_selector"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/txt_topic"
                    android:textColor="@color/radio_text_selector"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Here is **subject_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_ico_subject_active" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_ico_subject" />
</selector>
```

You have to create same `xml` for other `RadioButton`.

If you want to change the text color for selected `RadioButton` then here is xml. Put this xml file inside res>color>.

here is `radio_text_selector.xml` for text color.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:color="@color/dividerColor"/>
</selector>
```

Here is **output** looks like

[image]